# Toast in not show when i navigate one screen to another screen when i setTimeout 1000 it shown but i want to show toast without this in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
navigate("openshift")
 setTimeout(() => {
     showSuccessToast('Shift Assigned');
}, 1000);
```

/// BUT I want in this form showsucesstoast is file in which i have set Toast detail
navigate in which i am going to navigate one screen to another screen.

```
       navigate("openshift"); 
      showSuccessToast('Shift Assigned');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add some delay before navigating to other screen otherwise the process would be so fast, user won't be able to see the toast.
like this-

```
showSuccessToast('Shift Assigned');
setTimeout(() => {
     navigate("openshift")
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Is there any alternative of setTimeout in react native or JavaScript?